# search strings in multiple textfile

Tags: python, bash

I have thousands of text files on my disk.
I need to search for them in terms of selected words.
Currently, I use:

```
grep -Eri 'text1|text2|text3|textn' dir/ > results.txt
```

The result is saved to a file: results.txt
I would like the result to be saved to many files.

```
results_text1.txt, results_text2.txt, results_textn.txt
```

Maybe someone has encountered some kind of script eg in python?

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to use a bash for loop.

```
for word in text1 text2 text3 textn; do grep -Eri '$word' dir/ > results_$word.txt; done
```

You can run this directly from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

By using combination of "sed" and "xargs"

```
echo "text1,text2,text3,textn" | sed "s/,/\n/g" | xargs -I{} sh -c "grep -ir {} * > result_{}"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way (using Perl because it's easier for regex and one-liner).

Sample data:

```
% mkdir dir dir/dir1 dir/dir2
% echo -e "text1\ntext2\nnope" > dir/file1.txt
% echo -e "nope\ntext3" > dir/dir1/file2.txt
% echo -e "nope\ntext2" > dir/dir1/file3.txt
```

Search:

```
% find dir -type f -exec perl -ne '/(text1|text2|text3|textn)/ or next; 
    $pat = $1; unless ($fh{$pat}) { 
      ($fn = $1) =~ s/\W+/_/ag; 
      $fn = "results_$fn.txt"; 
      open $fh{$pat}, ">>", $fn;
    }
    print { $fh{$pat} } "$ARGV:$_"' {} \;
```

Content of results_text1.txt:

```
dir/file1.txt:text1
```

Content of results_text2.txt:

```
dir/dir2/file3.txt:text2
dir/file1.txt:text2
```

Content of results_text3.txt:

```
dir/dir1/file2.txt:text3
```

Note:

- you need to put the pattern inside parentheses to capture it. `grep` doesn't allow one to do this.
- the captured pattern is then filtered (`s/\W+/_/ag` means to replace nonalphanumeric characters with underscore) to ensure it's safe as part of a filename.